# Double join if row in third table matches where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a game server, and I want to get a list of the most-ignored player accounts.

I have a user table

```
Table1 - Users:
Name    | ID | otherstuff
Troll   | 1  | .
CoolGuy | 2  | .
```

I have an ignore table

```
Table2 - Ignores
id_UserWhoIsIgnoring | id_UserWhoIsIgnored
                   2 | 1
                   3 | 1
```

Now this is all great, and I can do something like:

```
select
  u.name,
  ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored,
  count(ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored) as ignoreCount
from ignores ig
  inner join users u
  on ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored = u.id
group by id_UserWhoIsIgnored
order by ignoreCount desc
limit 25;
```

But the problem with this is that I get accounts of users who haven't connected in a really long time. I'd like to limit my query to users connected in the past 30 days. I have a third table, `sessions`

```
Table3 - Sessions
id_user      | start_time          | otherstuff
1            | 2014-06-25 00:00:00 | .
(id)OldTroll | 2010-01-01 00:00:00 | .
```

How can I combine my first query giving the list but restrict it only cases `where start_time > date_sub(now(), interval 45 days)` gives me a result for id. In this case I don't want a row showing `OldTroll` even if they're the most ignored because their most recent connection is years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `start_time` is in the `users` table, then just use a `where`:

```
select u.name, ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored, count(ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored) as ignoreCount
from ignores ig inner join
     users u
     on ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored = u.id
where start_time > date_sub(now(), interval 45 days)
group by id_UserWhoIsIgnored
order by ignoreCount desc
limit 25;
```

If `start_time` is in the `ignores` table, then just use `having`:

```
select u.name, ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored, count(ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored) as ignoreCount
from ignores ig inner join
     users u
     on ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored = u.id
group by id_UserWhoIsIgnored
having max(start_time) > date_sub(now(), interval 45 days)
order by ignoreCount desc
limit 25;
```

EDIT:

Then I presume you want:

```
select u.name, ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored, count(ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored) as ignoreCount
from ignores ig inner join
     users u
     on ig.id_UserWhoIsIgnored = u.id inner join
     (select id_user, max(start_time) as start_time
      from sessions
      group by id_user
     ) s
     on u.id_user = s.id_user and
        s.start_time >= date_sub(now(), interval 45 days)
group by id_UserWhoIsIgnored
order by ignoreCount desc
limit 25;
```

Comment: I'm getting Empty Set returned from running that even though I have data in all 3 tables. The session subquery returns rows by itself as does my original user/ignore join example. I'm not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: @Daenyth . . . Maybe no one has been ignored in past 45 days.

Comment: @Daenyth . . . remove the condition on the `start_time` and put `max(s.start_time)` in the outer `select`.

Comment: I think you're right. I just realized the db snapshot I've been testing against ignores the sessions table when doing the snapshot.

Comment: That did it when I ran it on the real thing. Also locked the DB long enough for everyone to time out, but it did run ;)